# Uneven vertical space in tablenotes when using `subdepth`

Tags: equations, line-spacing, threeparttable

When using `subdepth`for nice looking equations, the tablenotes in `threeparttable` get messed up. Any idea how to get even vertical space between items in tablenotes? Have tried using `\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth}` with no good result.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subdepth}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    A = \frac{\left(\phi+\epsilon_A^\prime\right)-\epsilon_A}{\left(1+\epsilon_A^\prime\right)-\epsilon_A}
\end{equation}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{}
    \label{tableA}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
Name    & Value \\
\hline
TestA\tnote{a} & 1000000000000000000000000 \\
TestB & 10 \\
TestC & 10 \\
TestD & 10 \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
    \footnotesize   
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[a]{Salinity data from somewhere}
        \item[b]{Chemical product sheet}
        \item[c]{Standard density of water}
        \item[d]{Calculated value}
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{}
    \label{tableB}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
Name    & Value \\
\hline
TestA\tnote{a} & 1000000000000000000000000 \\
TestB & 10 \\
TestC & 10 \\
TestD & 10 \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
    \footnotesize   
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[a]{Salinity data from somewhere}
        \item[a]{Chemical product sheet}
        \item[a]{Standard density of water}
        \item[a]{Calculated value}
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For me the `low-sup` option works.

Comment: Yes @Bernard, it works for tablenotes, but then the subscript `A` is not aligned any longer in the equation :-(

Comment: The increased raising of the exponent causes the `b` line to be too high, so the `\lineskip` mechanism is used. This doesn't happen with the `a` exponent, because it lacks the ascender.

Comment: The suscript $A$ is not aligned w.r.t. what?

Comment: - to each other when you use `[low-sup]`

Comment: @egreg, can I use some `\phantom` function to mimic the vertical size of the letter `b` in all items?

Comment: `\vphantom{b}`in all items will do the job. Not the most beautiful solution, but it works!?!

Comment: You also can use `\item[\smash{b}]`.

Comment: One other ugly feature is the bad horizontal alignment of the text after the items. The letter `S` is far more to the left than the letter `C`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help of @egreg and @Bernard, I found a solution myself. Using either `\vphantom{b}` or `\smash{a-b-c-d}` will make the items align vertical. Notice I have added some horizontal space in the tablenotes to get the text proper aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subdepth}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    A = \frac{\left(\phi+\epsilon_A^\prime\right)-\epsilon_A}{\left(1+\epsilon_A^\prime\right)-\epsilon_A}
\end{equation}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{$\backslash$vphantom\{b\}}
    \label{tableA}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
Name    & Value \\
\hline
TestA\tnote{a} & 1000000000000000000000000 \\
TestB\tnote{b} & 10 \\
TestC\tnote{c} & 10 \\
TestD\tnote{d} & 10 \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
    \footnotesize   
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[\vphantom{b}a]{\hspace{0.3pt}Salinity data from somewhere}
        \item[\vphantom{b}b]{\hspace{-.3pt}Chemical product sheet}
        \item[\vphantom{b}c]{\hspace{0.3pt}Standard density of water}
        \item[\vphantom{b}d]{\hspace{-.3pt}Calculated value}
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{$\backslash$smash\{a-b-c-d\}}
    \label{tableB}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
Name    & Value \\
\hline
TestA\tnote{a} & 1000000000000000000000000 \\
TestB\tnote{b} & 10 \\
TestC\tnote{c} & 10 \\
TestD\tnote{d} & 10 \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
    \footnotesize   
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[\smash{a}]{\hspace{0.3pt}Salinity data from somewhere}
        \item[\smash{b}]{\hspace{-.3pt}Chemical product sheet}
        \item[\smash{c}]{\hspace{0.3pt}Standard density of water}
        \item[\smash{d}]{\hspace{-.3pt}Calculated value}
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the different horizontal alignment of text after the footnote labels is because the horizontal space allowed for the labels is only `.5em` (defined in `\TPTnoteSettings`), which is a hair too narrow for many letters.  redefining the width of this space in  the preamble (by patching the definition of `\TPTnoteSettings`) would be cleaner than adjusting individual lines of the notes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I tried using @Heiko Oberdiek solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181015/49888, with `\labelsep` instead of `\itemsep`, but it will not align the text, it only add space between label and text. Is there another function to use instead? Thanks.